# AWS cross-AZ traffic - for private endpoint access

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, availability-zone

I have a k8 deployment in az2 , az4 and az6.  The services deployed in these zones need to access a private endpoint configured to access third party service. The private endpoint can only be configured for az1 , az2 and az4.

How can I setup a cross-AZ traffic so that k8 services deployed in az6 can access the private endpoint? Thanks!

Comment: you can't.  Switch to AZ1.

Comment: @erik258 would I be able to route my k8 az6 traffic thru either az2 or az4?

Comment: it would probably be *possible* but inconvenient.  The whole point of VPC Endpoints is that the same API hostnames work transparently without client side configuration.  Much easier to just add nodes in AZ1 and remove in AZ6